# How to add an action on button touch up in iOS storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I am new to iOS app development. I am going through the dev guides. My app has two views - one with a button and clicking that button launches a new view. I added a segue to launch the new view and was able to link it to the button. But its not clear to me what the exact action that launches the new view and how I can handle that action. I want to do some network operation before launching the new view and so want to handle that button click event (touch up). Can I get Xcode to generate a dummy handler function for that specific event?

Comment: Try to get away from connecting segues to buttons.  See my answer below for the "Why?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't connect the `segue` to the button, connect the segue to the View Controller itself, then in the button's `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    // If you need to do some other work prior to firing the segue, do it here.

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:nil];
}
```

Then do your prep work in the prepareForSegue method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        // Do my stuff here
    }
}
```

I hardly ever connect `segues` to `UIButton`s, `UITableCell`s, etc, I connect them to my VC and then in the action, call the segue.  This gives you more control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I get the app to fire the myButtonTapped function? That is the connection I am missing.

Comment: You use the assistant editor to CTRL drag from the button to the `ViewController` and change the type to `IBAction`, choose TouchUp Inside and then follow the prompts.

Comment: Sorry to be like this but I am able to drag from the button to the ViewController but not able to edit it to choose the TouchUp Inside. Is there something I should do to get this? I am trying to do this in the ConnectionsInspector where I see the action as action -> { custom, ViewController }

Comment: You just need to learn how to use the Assistant Editor.  Try searching YouTube or watch this one (did a quick search) - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5N8K5YrtmY

Comment: Yep. Never occured to me look on Youtube actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Storyboard and segues to launch a new view using an `UIButton` the action that launches the new view is `prepareForSegue:sender:`. What network operation do you want to do before launching the view? For example if you need to know if the device is online or not **before** launching the view and launch it *only* if the device has internet access you could also use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and an `if statement` inside it.

For example:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if ("The device has internet access")
    {
        return NO; // The view won't be launched
    }

    else
    {
        return YES; // We have internet, launch the view
    }
}
```

This will make the view launch able only when the device has internet access, if not anything will happen.

Answer (score 0):

On the view controller that holds the storyboard, implement this method :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        // Implement your network operation here 

    } 
}
```

It will get executed before the segue happens.